# Error: WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete

Tags: netplan

I am using systemd-networkd to render network interfaces, in the initial network configuration i had a network
connection, but as soon as i boot into the bridged network via the netplan config it causes some errors for me. At first, i had the bridge-utils package installed for debugging.

i execute the command:

`networkctl`

and i have unloaded interfaces:

```
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged 
  2 ens33            ether              n/a         unmanaged 
  3 enp4s5           ether              n/a         unmanaged 
  4 tap0             ether              n/a         unmanaged 
  5 br0              ether              n/a         unmanaged
```

How can I enable the display of interfaces in this case?

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem (physical access to the host is required):

`sudo apt update ; sudo apt install netplan ; reboot`

and after that the error disappears, i have all my interfaces listed.